# load swf file at (X,Y) position

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Greeting,
I have the listed code to load swf file to the stage using action script 3 and I want to modify it to place the swf in (X,Y) place.

what I should add to the code to have the swf file placed in the specify position.

Thank you,

```
var swfLoader:Loader = new Loader();

stage.addChild(swfLoader);

var bgURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("test.swf");

swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadProdComplete);

swfLoader.load(bgURL);

function loadProdComplete(e:Event):void {

trace("file loaded");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add:

after stage.addChild(swfLoader);

```
swfLoader.x = 100;
swfLoader.y = 100;
```

That should be it. Of course 100 is to be replaced with the values you need.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I placed the two lines of code after loading swf file but it disappear from the stage and I tried to place the in different places and I got sane result.where I should place the two lines?

Comment: i think it depends on where this script is seeing the registration point. if the AS is on the main timeline it should work but if this code is in a child timeline of a movieclip you should consider where this is on the stage

Comment: Try changing from stage.addChild to just this.addChild. Also, make sure that the file is loading correctly.